# Postgres error invalid memory alloc request size

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres database for my backend on a website. The website allows a user to upload a file of up to 1GB, but I've found that only file sizes of around 500MB are possible at the moment.

When you try to upload a 1GB file, there is an error on the database side, below is the error log. Google searches for this error have people saying its due to a corrupted table, but I've tried with different files and different configurations and can't seem to make a 1GB file upload work.

Is there a way to increase the memory alloc request size to avoid this error?

Thanks!

EDB postgres log:

```
Jun 28 05:01:40 udb1fo postgres[8291]: [57-1] 2016-06-28 05:01:40 EDT plf_jcr plf uweb1fo(56525) 8291 57723b77.2063 2016-06-28 04:55:19 EDTERROR:  XX000: invalid memory alloc request size 1133936643
Jun 28 05:01:40 udb1fo postgres[8291]: [57-2] 2016-06-28 05:01:40 EDT plf_jcr plf uweb1fo(56525) 8291 57723b77.2063 2016-06-28 04:55:19 EDTLOCATION:  palloc, mcxt.c:664
Jun 28 05:01:40 udb1fo postgres[8291]: [57-3] 2016-06-28 05:01:40 EDT plf_jcr plf uweb1fo(56525) 8291 57723b77.2063 2016-06-28 04:55:19 EDTSTATEMENT:  insert into JCR_SVALUE(DATA, ORDER_NUM, PROPERTY_ID, STORAGE_DESC) VALUES($1,$2,$3,$4)
Jun 28 05:01:40 udb1fo postgres[8291]: [58-1] 2016-06-28 05:01:40 EDT plf_jcr plf uweb1fo(56525) 8291 57723b77.2063 2016-06-28 04:55:19 EDTERROR:  25P02: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

Platform (web) log:

```
Jun 28 06:28:15 uweb1fo exo-platform: Caused by: org.exoplatform.services.jcr.impl.storage.JCRInvalidItemStateException: [collaboration] ADD PROPERTY. Error of item add. []:1[]Groups:1[]spaces:1[]administration_community:1[]Documents:1[]distribution-2.1-bin (1).tar:1[http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0]content:1[http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0]data:1, ID: 968c5312ac1d1ca1032b68d6d07b8b47, ParentID: 968c5311ac1d1ca15749805d270795ee. Cause >>>> ERROR: invalid memory alloc request size 1133936643: ERROR: invalid memory alloc request size 1133936643
```

Comment: If you're running 32-bit PostgreSQL and storing data in a `bytea` field you can run out of memory very easily. PostgreSQL does not use memory efficiently with large binary fields.

Comment: thanks but we are using 64-bit PostgresSQL, any other ideas?

Comment: I think that I am stuck in your same problem. What PostgreSQL version are you using? Are you still stuck with that problem? Any clues?